# JQuery Plugin camera

Tags: jquery, css

http://jsfiddle.net/Rs8F5/

1) How to make the image smaller than the slider container so that the text would be on right? the caption is at the bottom - still figuring how to make it move to right in full column. Image would appear in full width. I wanted to cut it half size so that text can go in another half.

2) There is a problem with image - images are supposed to slide from right then suddenly the last image would have different transition. I also couldn't figure it out.

Any insight or help on these will be appreciated. Thank you